# Texturing on a circle with "Ngon" as the filling not working?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

I am making a table and the top of it is a stretched out circle with Ngon as the filling. I have tried to import a Image Texture but it will not work. I am using cycles and the most recent blender version. This is what it looks like in preview using 32 samples..

[image]

How i fixed this: i used a sphere and stretched it out to make a circle. now my texturing works.

Comment: How have you imported said image? Have you created a new material for it? Have you assigned that material to your object? Have you provided it with UV coordinates? Have you unwrapped your object?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos i selected the object, created a material, added a image texture, went into edit mode, pressed "U" and then selected Smart UV unwrap or whatever it is called.

Comment: Can you edit you question and shows us the results of those steps? Please post some screenshots of your material setup, material slots, unwrapped object and corresponding image texture.

Comment: sure @DuarteFarrajotaRamos i can add a .blend file to make it more easy.

Comment: finally added it :)

Comment: anyone else??  :(

Comment: You didn't pack you texture, I can't see anything, so here goes a bunch of wild guesses: Avoid NGons, use proper topology, prefer quads, apply object scale, provide your texture with explicit texture coordinates in your material nodes.